# Is the notion of a 2-category introduced to fix/forget the size issues in the definition of (an ordinary) category?

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory, higher-category-theory

A category $\mathcal{C}$ consists of pair of classes $(\mathcal{C}_0, \mathcal{C}_1)$, along with maps $$\mathcal{C}_1\times_{\mathcal{C}_0}\mathcal{C}_1\rightarrow
\mathcal{C}_1\rightrightarrows \mathcal{C}_0\rightarrow\mathcal{C}_1.$$

A category is called small, locally small, large, depending on the size of the class $\mathcal{C}_1$.

- If $\mathcal{C}_1$ is a set (which would imply $\mathcal{C}_0$ is a set), then, $\mathcal{C}$ is called a small category.
- If $\mathcal{C}_1$ is a proper class, but $\mathcal{C}(a,b)$ is a set for each $a,b\in \mathcal{C}_0$, then, $\mathcal{C}$ is called a locally small category.
- Anything that does not fall in above two cases is called a large category.

A $2$-category is described to be something, that comes with a class $\mathcal{C}_0$, a category $\mathcal{C}(a,b)$ for each $a,b\in \mathcal{C}_0$, some more data satisfying some conditions.

If I start with a category that is not locally small, I know that, $\mathcal{C}(a,b)$ is not a set. Is it then a "better idea" to consider it as a category, along with some compatibility conditions, instead of "feeling bad" that it is not a set?

Is this how the notion of a $2$-category came into picture?

Is the size issue, in any way, related to the necessity of introducing the notion of a $2$-category?

Does the same justification hold in introducing the notion of an $n$-category?

If none of the above has a fairly positive answer, is there a way to introduce the notion of a $2$-category as an outcome of trying to fix the size issue in ordinary category theory? Is there a way to introduce the notion of a $n+1$-category as an outcome of trying to fix the size issue in an $n$-category?

Comment: As other people will describe here better than I can, 2- (and other higher dimensional) categories arise from the **natural algebraic properties** of categories themselves, of homotopies in and between spaces, or analogous ideas for computational processes and many other **real mathematical** situations.  The so-called size issue is a set theoretic disease with which they infect other mathematicians and then claim to cure using more of the same poison.

Comment: can you expand your last sentence? I do not fully understand what does it mean @Paul Taylor.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Paul seems to be claiming (correct me if I'm wrong) that the 'size issue' you bring up is an unnecessary artifact of formalizing mathematics in set theory, not actually tied to anything intrinsic about the mathematics at hand. I think this is incorrect, and expanded on my opinion below.

Comment: @AlecRhea thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @PaulTaylor Russell’s paradox is not our fault.

Comment: My recollection is that 2-categories were due to Charles Ehresmann, who was a differential geometer, not a logician by any stretch. Wikipedia, confirming my guess, even says they were a special case of enriched categories more generally, so even further from size concerns. It is a post-hoc argument that maybe size issues can be dealt with using suitable 2-categorical ideas.

Comment: @DavidRoberts "It is a post-hoc argument that maybe size issues can be dealt with using suitable 2-categorical ideas." I wanted to ask something along these lines.. If there is any way to interpret size issue using some $2$-categorical ideas.

Comment: Not _just_ 2-categorical ideas. Some care is needed. Since if you are looking at the 3-category of 2-categories, one of which is the 2-category of categories, one of which is the category of sets, then there are some seriously careful things that need to be done to avoid any size paradoxes. Doing one level is ok (like doing an axiomatic "Elementary Theory of the 2-Category of Categories" ([link](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCC#ET2CC)), but pushing this further is tricky.

Answer (score 3):

Historically, the introduction of higher categories has nothing to do with set-theoretic size issues to my knowledge. Promoting the hom-sets of a non-locally small category into (presumably discrete) categories doesn't add any additional information, since there wouldn't be any interesting new data in these categories; as objects they would have the arrows of the hom sets, and their only 'arrows on arrows' would be identity arrows. We could then speak about functors into/out of them, but I don't see what that gets us off the top of my head. See below for an account of how we can naturally arrive at the definitions of higher categories, but that seems secondary to your question.

The 'size-issue' that you bring up is something that occurs when we try to consider a 'thing of all things', without delineating between the first usage of the word 'thing' and the second usage of the word 'things'. The classic example is  [Russell's paradox](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Russell%27s+paradox) which arises when we try to consider the set of all sets, and this leads mathematicians to believe that it is a set-theoretic issue, but in type theory we have the analogous [Girard's paradox](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Burali-Forti%27s+paradox#GirardParadox) when we try to consider the [type of all types](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/type+of+types).

This can be rectified in set theory by considering a hierarchy of collections like sets/classes/super-classes etc., or by using a method like [Grothendieck universes](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+universe) and considering a hierarchy of universes

$$V_0\subseteq V_1\subseteq V_2\subseteq\dots$$

Analogously, in type theory we can rectify the paradox by considering a hierarchy of types

$${\sf Type}_0:{\sf Type}_1,\ {\sf Type}_1:{\sf Type}_2,\dots$$

In any case the paradox seems to arise when we try to treat 'all things of a certain nature' as 'a thing of that same nature', in a certain sense that is independent of sets or types or whatever formalism we choose. I do not think there is any need for 'size envy' towards set theorists :). There are foundations like [NF](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/New+Foundations) that allow for a set of all sets by baking the required stratification into the axiom system (in this case the comprehension axiom is stratified), but they have other strange properties -- in NF for example, the category of sets is not Cartesian closed.

In order to answer your last question, what do you mean by 'fixing' the issue? There are advantages and disadvantages to all the different approaches to rectifying this paradox, and which one a person uses depends on the needs at hand. Do you want a formalism that lets you talk about 'all the things of a smaller nature', like with classes/universes/type hierarchies? Do you want a formalism that makes it so the 'things' are naturally stratified, like NF? An answer to this question would help us maybe think of some natural formalism using higher categories, but I think it's doubtful anything 'canonical' will arise.

---

Although the following account is probably not historically accurate, it is a canonical path up the abstraction ladder from categories to higher categories.

Beginning with a notion of set, it's natural to define a notion of function between sets -- when combining these notions into one structure, we naturally arrive at the definition of a category.

Now that we have categories we can naturally define functors between them, but the increased depth in the definition of a functor allows us to canonically define a notion of natural transformation *between functors*. If we want to collect the notions of a category and functor and natural transformation into a single structure, we naturally arrive at the definition of a $2$-category.

Now that we have $2$-categories we can naturally define $2$-functors and $2$-natural transformations between $2$-functors, but the increased depth in the definition of a $2$-natural transformation allows us to canonically define a notion of modification *between $2$-natural transformations*. If we want to collect together notions of $2$-categories, $2$-functors, $2$-natural transformations and modifications together into one structure, we naturally arrive at the definition of a $3$-category.

Rinse and repeat to move higher up the (strict) higher-category ladder, and weaken equality (down to iso/equivalence/adjunction/$n$-cell etc.) as necessary for pseudo/quasi/lax etc. versions.

Comment: +1... I know (and to some extent understand) the notion of $2$-category... Thanks for your answer... I do not have anything specific to say. I will read one more time and write if I have anything specific..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I wasn't trying to imply you didn't understand $2$-categories, apologies if it came off that way; I was just trying to illustrate how they can be seen as a natural 'step up' in the categorical abstraction ladder, and how they suggest the existence of a 'next step', and this 'next step' itself suggests the existence of a step after that, etc.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Perhaps more importantly, I meant to show how each 'next step' into abstraction is canonically suggested by the current step, all the way up the abstraction ladder. Things get a little hairier trying to get your teeth into infinity-categories using this type of intuition, but it works well for finite higher categories.

Comment: I did not mean you mean I do not understand $2$-categories. I was casually saying that.. :) Thanks for your time and answer..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik My pleasure, I enjoy having an excuse to go on about these things... :)